# an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement (PLSQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having an error when creating a procedure. Still learning how to create procedures.

I tried to declare it and it still didn't work

```
  create or replace procedure CustomersSpentOver100(cs  varchar)
  As
  begin

   select customer_name, (order_total + tip_amount) AS "Amount Spent"
   from Resturauntorder
   where (order_total + tip_amount) > 100;
   dbms_output.put_line(cs);
   end;
```

The procedure doesn't compile and expects an into

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please tag database name on which you are working.

Comment: @stickybit Trying to create a procedure that lists the names. Then I was having trouble calling it.

Comment: Why do you need a procedure for this? If you must "print" the result set of a query, use a SQL SELECT statement, not wrapped within PL/SQL code. If your query must return a result that depends on an input (`cs` in your example), make that a bind variable, which is a user input. Except that in your code, you are not using that variable anywhere **in the query** anyway, so what's the point of your whole procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `INTO` clause to get value into a variable from a `select` query.

For more details : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm

```
create or replace procedure CustomersSpentOver100(cs  varchar)
  As
  v_customer_name Resturauntorder.customer_name%type;
  v_amt_spent number;
  begin

   for r in (
   select customer_name, (order_total + tip_amount) AS Amount_Spent
   from Resturauntorder
   where (order_total + tip_amount) > 100) loop

   dbms_output.put_line('customer_name='||r.customer_name);
   dbms_output.put_line('Amount_Spent='||r.Amount_Spent);

   end loop;

  end;
```

Comment: Sorry to bother but when executing I get an error. EXEC CustomersSpentOver100(cs);

Comment: @Sas Did your query output multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to print the customer's list spent over 100 rs. through procedure. Oracle does not function like this. It uses ref_cursor to achieve this. You may change your procedure to -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CustomersSpentOver100(CS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN CS FOR
    SELECT customer_name, (order_total + tip_amount) AS "Amount Spent"
    FROM Resturauntorder
    WHERE (order_total + tip_amount) > 100;
END CustomersSpentOver100;
```

You can further use this procedure in your application.

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_cname   Resturauntorder.customer_name%TYPE;
  l_amount  number;
BEGIN
     CustomersSpentOver100 (CS => l_cursor);
     LOOP 
         FETCH l_cursor
         INTO  l_cname, l_amount;
         EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cname || ' | ' || l_amount);
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
```

For further details read the documentation

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, in Oracle we use PL/SQL, a programming language, to write stored procedures. We can use SQL inside it to get us a result set, but we must tell the DBMS how to retrieve it and what to do with it. More or less like in any other programming language, we can read the SQL result row by row or read it into an array.

Here is how to read a query result in a loop:

```
create or replace procedure customers_spent_over_100 as
begin
  for rec in 
  (
    select customer_name, order_total + tip_amount as amount_spent
    from resturauntorder
    where order_total + tip_amount > 100
  ) loop   
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.customer_name || ' spent ' || rec.amount_spent);
  end loop;
end customers_spent_over_100;
```

And here is how to read the result into an array:

```
create or replace procedure customers_spent_over_100 as
  type myrecordtype is record (customer_name varchar2(100), amount_spent number(8,2));
  type mytabletype is table of myrecordtype;
  v_myarray mytabletype;
begin
  select customer_name, order_total + tip_amount as amount_spent
  bulk collect into v_myarray
  from resturauntorder
  where order_total + tip_amount > 100;

  for i = 1 .. v_myarray.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_myarray(i).customer_name || ' spent ' || v_myarray(i).amount_spent);
  end loop;
end customers_spent_over_100;
```

Comment: A "programming language" never returns anything anyway. What are you trying to say at the beginning of your reply?

Comment: @mathguy: Well, what *did* I want to say? I think I meant to say that in Oracle we are using a programming language to write stored procedures, which is different from some other DBMS, where SQL is being used, so their stored procedures produce query results. Now that you mention it, it sounds strange to me, too. I'll think of a different wording or remove it.

Comment: So, I've edited my answer and hope this explanation is better now :-)

Comment: Much better! :)

Answer (score 0):

Into clause is missing...check the syntax of query and it should be ok..